# Hyperbolic system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Could you please help me with this exercise.

If  $\; x^{'}=Ax \;$ and $\; x^ {'} = Bx \;$ are hyperbolic systems and $\; AB = BA \;$ then $\; x^{'} = (A + B)x \;$ is also a hyperbolic system.

My solution:

$$e^{A+B} = e^{A} \; e^{B}$$
from the equation $AB = BA$. It follows that:
$$A^2 B = A (BA) = (AB)A = (BA)A = B A^2$$
is defenined:
\begin{align} x^{'} &= (A+B) e^{t(A+B)} - A e^{tA} e^{tB} - e^{tA} Be^{tB}\\
x^{'} &= (A+B) e^{t(A+B)} - (A+B) e^{tA} e^{tB}\\
x^{'} &= (A+B)x.
\end{align}

Am I correct?

Comment: if $A$  and $B$ commute then $e^{(A+B)t} = e^{At] e^{Bt} $

Comment: then x'=(A+B)x is also a hyperbolic system.